# Software to predict gamma ray spectrum from dark matter decay and anihilation

Tags: astrophysics, resource-recommendations, dark-matter, software, gamma-rays

Im looking to study the gamma ray spectra of dark matter models. Is there a "standard" or widely used software that can produce these spectra given some user defined model?

Comment: Until there is an established physics, you are not likely to see a canonical event generator; at this stage most people roll their own. After all, you specify that you're going to define the model, so why would you expect someone else to have provided code for that model?

Comment: The downvote may be a little harsh: you have to be in contact with the community to know how things are actually practiced and I would have expected someone in that position to know and use the phrase "event generator" in this context.

Comment: Well I was trying to make the question as open as possible. Im aware that Pythia is used as the standard event generator and used as a back end for GamBit and sometimes micrOmegas is also used. but I was asking which one is most used/accepted as the standard. 
Furthermore, model building and calculation of gamma ray yield are independent of each other. Anyone with a cursory knowledge of field theory can calculate the annihilation spectrum, but adding radiative corrections and cascade decays is something that is best handled through software and has been implemented in many software packages.

Comment: It would have been advisable to include those details in your original question. It's not too late! Anyway, +1 to rectify.

Answer (score 0):

CLUMPY: A code for gamma-ray signals from dark matter structures ([arXiv:1201.4728v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4728)). Here is the abstract for convenience:

> We present the first public code for semi-analytical calculation of the gamma-ray flux astrophysical J-factor from dark matter annihilation/decay in the Galaxy, including dark matter substructures. The core of the code is the calculation of the line of sight integral of the dark matter density squared (for annihilations) or density (for decaying dark matter). The code can be used in three modes: i) to draw skymaps from the Galactic smooth component and/or the substructure contributions, ii) to calculate the flux from a specific halo (that is not the Galactic halo, e.g. dwarf spheroidal galaxies) or iii) to perform simple statistical operations from a list of allowed DM profiles for a given object. Extragalactic contributions and other tracers of DM annihilation (e.g. positrons, antiprotons) will be included in a second release.